# Clarification about the definition of a metric on a vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $E$ be a vector bundle over a manifold $M$. By definition, a metric on $E$ is a function $g:E \times _M E \to M \times \mathbb{R}$. [In wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28vector_bundle%29), they say $g$ is a bundle map.

However, it is not linear on the fibers. The fiber $E_p \times E_p$ has the vector structure of the direct sum, while $g$ is bi-linear. (Hence $g_p$ is not linear).

So, $g$ is a morphism of fiber bundles, not of vector bundles.

Wouldn't it be more natural to define $g:E \otimes E \to M \times\mathbb{R}$ where now it is linear on the fibers?

Comment: I agree that the definition you suggest is more natural. My preferred definition is that a bundle metric is a section of the bundle $S^2E^*$, which is postive definite in each point.